# VBA Excel - Last two cells in selected row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of a problem. I need to set last two cells in selected row(s) to 0.
I'm pretty new in VBA and don't know what to use to achieve that.

This is what I have so far and it's working just values are hard-coded (for cells).

```
Sub SetCellValueToZero()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        Cells(r.Row, 3) = "0"
        Cells(r.Row, 2) = "0"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Comment: last cells meaning those furthest to the right? `lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(35, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: If there is a row having one less entry then the other, do you want to delete these two entrys or just the last 2 columns at all?

Comment: Hmmm not following :) 
Just want to set last two used cells to 0 in selected row. In languages that I use it's easy :))

Comment: The whole row or just the last two in a given column?  When you select the cells are you selecting multiple columns or just one?

Comment: Just last two (used) cells in selected row(s).

Comment: Not sure why you don't follow XD `Cells(r.Row, lastCol) = "0" | Cells(r.Row, lastCol-1) = "0"` Edit: obviously change 35 to r.row.

Comment: @findwindow you are might want to put it all together this time in an answer, so you can explain what each does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub SetCellValueToZero()
Dim r As Range
Dim lastCol as Long
For Each r In Selection.Rows
    lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(r.row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Cells(r.Row, lastCol-1) = "0"
    Cells(r.Row, lastCol) = "0"
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude at least declare `lastCol`

Comment: Just FYI, It was not me who down voted you. I wish people would have the decency to at least explain their down vote.

Comment: @ScottCraner I know it wasn't you. Guessing it's due to lack of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To find the rightmost used cell in a row you can use `Range.End(xlToLeft)` as findwindow is hinting at in the comments to your question. What the [`End(<direction>)`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does is the equivalent of pressing End+-key in Excel. So if you do it from the rightmost cell of the row you are searching, it will give you the last cell (unless the rightmost cell is used). To find the rightmost cell in a sheet, you do `ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)`.

Putting  all of this together, your macro would look something like this:

```
Sub SetCellValueToZero()
  Dim last_used_cell As Range, r As Range

  For Each r In Selection.Rows
    Set last_used_cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    last_used_cell = "0"
    last_used_cell.Offset(0, -1) = "0"
  Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function getLastColumn(ByVal inputRng As Range) As Single
Dim nColumn As Single
    nColumn = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    nColumn = inputRng.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    getLastColumn = nRow
End Function
```

last2Row = getLastColumn - 1